# Wildcarding for email in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, wildcard

This is the sample email data in table

```
2.3|[johnnyappleseed@example.com]
```

Below is a query that I have been working on for a little while:

```
SELECT * FROM WS_TRANSACTION
WHERE SERVICE_ID = 'GETUSERTOKENLOGIN' 
       AND SERVICE_ID LIKE '%@%'
```

What this is supposed to do is give me the data from this table, and make the column service_id only contain emails, like the johnnyappleseed email. Is there a wild card out there for SQL that will delete that useless stuff so that it only portrays the emails, or do I have to go about this in a different way?

I tried to get the email by using the percent signs, but I believe that its deleting everything before and after the @ which is not what I want.

Any help would be very appreciative

Comment: so you need only words before @ in email?

Comment: No I need the whole email. I dont need the 2.3 | [ ] stuff. Sorry I can see how that can be a little misleading

Comment: you have email wrap in between [ ] in your database?

Comment: Its just how they got logged in I guess

Comment: which sql server version, you are using?

Comment: Where only finds a row.  Where or wildcard does not modify anything.  You need to separate search from formatting.   Regex is the best way to extract that information and regex is not built into SQL.

Comment: is `SERVICE_ID = 'GETUSERTOKENLOGIN' AND SERVICE_ID LIKE '%@%'` a typo?  Otherwise, this will never evaluate to true.

Comment: @Blam if regex is the only way possible, then would be willing to tell me what the regex will be? I have an idea on what I will do, but I am not good with regex so I will need a little help with it. Also can you do it in c#? You would really help me out in that

Comment: I did not say only.  I said best.  I cannot do regex from memory.  c# is just a language.  I don't think there is single langue that has regex baked in.  I get you are new but SO is not a code generation service.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can get the Substring to get the email, As you said you have Email wrap in square brackets '[ ]', So use SubString()

```
Declare @a varchar(max)
SET @a = '2.3|[johnnyappleseed@example.com]'
SELECT  SUBSTRING(@a,CharIndex('[',@a)+1,(CharIndex(']',@a)-CharIndex('[',@a))-1);
```

[SEE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e716c/16)

Answer (score 0):

IF length of the characters at the beginning and the end of the string are always the same, you could use LEFT and RIGHT functions, along with the LEN function like this.

```
SELECT LEFT(RIGHT(SERVICE_ID,LEN(SERVICE_ID)-5),LEN(SERVICE_ID)-6)
```

Answer (score 0):

if your columns with email are automatically logged with the data you represented, and you only want the email portion use:

```
replace(replace(SUBSTRING('2.3 | [johnnyappleseed@example.com]', (charindex( '[','2.3 | [johnnyappleseed@example.com]')), LEN('2.3 | [johnnyappleseed@example.com]')),'[',''),']','')
```

output is

```
johnnyappleseed@example.com
```